# Is there a better way to avoid folder permission issues for docker containers launched from docker compose in manjaro?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, archlinux, manjaro

Is there better way to avoid folder permission issues when a relative folder is being set in a docker compose file when using manjaro?

For instance, take the bitnami/elasticsearch:7.7.0 image as an example:

This image as an example will always throw the `ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/bitnami/elasticsearch/data/nodes];` error.

I can get around in by:

- create the data directory with sudo, followed by chmod 777
- attaching a docker volume

But I am looking for a bit easier to manage solution, similar to the docker experience in Ubuntu and OSX which I do not have to first create a directory with root in order for folder mapping to work.

I have made sure that my user is in the docker group by following the post install instructions on docker docs. I have no permission issues when accessing `docker info`, or sock.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
  elasticsearch:
    image: bitnami/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports: 
      - 9200:9200
    networks: 
      - proxy
    environment: 
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HEAP_SIZE=512m
    volumes: 
      - ./data/:/bitnami/elasticsearch/data
      - ./config/elasticsearch.yml:/opt/bitnami/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

networks: 
  proxy:
    external: true
```

I am hoping for a more seamless experience when using my compose files from git which works fine in other systems, but running into this permission issue on the data folder on manjaro.

I did check other posts on SO, some some are temporary, like disabling selinux, while other require running docker with the `--privileged` flag, but I am trying to do with from compose.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the Linux distribution but is a general problem with Docker and bind mounts. A bind mount is when you mount a directory of your host into a container. The problem is that the Docker daemon creates the directory under the user it runs with (root) and the UID/GIDs are mapped literally into the container.

Not that it is advisable to run as root, but depending on your requirements, the official Elasticsearch image (elasticsearch:7.7.0) runs as root and does not have this problem.

Another solution that would work for the bitnami image is to make the ./data directory owned by group root and group writable, since it appears the group of the Elasticsearch process is still root.

A third solution is to change the GID of the bitnami image to whatever group you had the data created with and make it group writable.

Comment: Yes, you are right, these are all valid options, but I am trying to avoid this cumbersome process for every single time i use compose on a bind mounted directory. In my OP, I am using elasticsearch as an example, but the issue prevails with any image really.

Comment: Yes it is indeed cumbersome, but Docker is inheriting the permissions from the host FS and there is nothing that can be done about it. Again, nothing special with your distribution. Best bet is probably that Compose gets support for init containers. Then you could create the directories specifically.

Comment: Ah fair enough. I know in ubuntu it doesnt fight back this much based on my experience, so it is just annoying. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: The problem occurs in all Linux distributions, but is observed in Docker images where the default user is not root. Many official images are run as root despite Docker recommendation not to do so. I suppose this is one of the reasons...